# Visio 2010 to Excel 2010

Tags: excel, visio

I have a visio file converted to XML format and in that Visio file i want to extract the content of visio diagram, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on whether by content you mean the visuals or data, but essentially you can just process the xml in any way you choose.  I'd start off over here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visio/archive/2011/05/31/visio-2010-xml-schema-definition-released.aspx

Comment: do we any tool or software to do

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at my answer. I believe it will help you do what you are looking for.

[Visio 2010 C# Entity Automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475099/visio-2010-c-sharp-entity-automation/11675571#11675571)

You will probably have to do a bit of work on your own based on the shapes you are working with. This is in C# (sorry not that familiar with VBA), but this should set you in the right direction.